# "apply is not a function" when using dojo.connect with an item of dijit.WidgetSet

Tags: dojo, dijit.form

I have a set of dijit.form.CheckBoxe(s) on myJSP.jsp.
In my dojo class myClass.js, I try to grab these checkboxes and connect to each of them a function which should be called on an "onClick" event:

```
(dijit.registry.byClass("dijit.form.CheckBox")).forEach(function(checkBox){
    dojo.connect(checkBox,"onClick",this,this.checkboxClicked);
});
```

When I click on any of the checkboxes, I get the following message: *"lls[i].apply is not a function"*.

Why can't I use dojo.connect?
Btw - I use IBM Websphere Portal 6.1.5's dojo version, which is 1.3.2.

Comment: Don't know, should work.  But 1.3 is quite old.  You may want to upgrade to 1.6.1 which is the latest.  Also you should be able to do `checkBox.connect("onClick", this, this.checkboxClicked)` for more concise code.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't upgrade.
As for the `checkBox.connect` - it has no impact, I mean: for some reason it doesn't connect the function `this.checkboxClicked` to my checkboxes, so that when I press them the function isn't called.

Comment: Oops.  I think I missed this.  I vaguely remember the Dojo checkbox traps the onClick event for its internal processing.  You may have to use the "onChange" event instead.  Check the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The cause is that `this` in the `forEach` callback function actually refers to the global object and `this.checkboxClicked` is actually `undefined`.

To fix that, use the second parameter in the `forEach` function to specify the scope object, i.e. the `this` object.

Below code may work depends on whether the `this` object when invoking this function is the same one that has the `checkboxClicked` function. If it's not, you can change to use other object.

```
(dijit.registry.byClass("dijit.form.CheckBox")).forEach(function(checkBox){
dojo.connect(checkBox,"onClick",this,this.checkboxClicked);
}, this);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. I still get the _"lls[i].apply is not a function"_ message.